# Use python ctypes array data in cython functions

Tags: python, cython, ctypes

I have python ctypes array. I would like to use it in cython def and cdef functions.

```
import ctypes
from my_cython_extention import *

class Test_Node(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("i", ctypes.c_int),
        ("f", ctypes.c_float),
    ]
my_array = (Test_Node * 10)()
my_cython_function(my_array)
```

How should I define cython function `my_cython_function` to access `my_array data`? Can I get `my_array` C++ data pointer?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to the question:

```
cdef my_cython_function_c(
    Test_Node *arr_addr, int arr_size
):
    for i in range(arr_size):
        printf("%i\n", arr_addr.i)
        inc(arr_addr)

def my_cython_function(arr):
    my_cython_function_c(<Test_Node *><long>ctypes.addressof(arr), len(arr))
```

Comment: To make this platform independent, instead of `long`, use `intptr_t` defined in `'stdint.h'`